# Insert variable from parameter into Sql Command query

Tags: asp.net, sql, parameter-passing

This is my code in class file:

```
public class terminarzLiga
{
    public static List<terminarz> wyswietlTerminarz(string liga)
    {
        List<terminarz> wyswietlTerminarz = new List<terminarz>();
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ligiConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from TerminarzLaLiga", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
             [.... rest of code .....]
```

My intention is use variable in Sql Command query, like this: 
Code behind:

```
private void ZaladujGridView()
{
    GridView2.DataSource = EuroPilka.terminarzLiga.wyswietlTerminarz("TerminarzLaLiga");
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Class file code:

```
public class terminarzLiga
{
    public static List<terminarz> wyswietlTerminarz(string liga)
    {
        List<terminarz> wyswietlTerminarz = new List<terminarz>();
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ligiConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from '" + liga +"'", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
             [.... rest of code .....]
```

but i'am receiving error while reader is executing

```
SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
```

Many thanks for any advise !

Comment: Remove the quotes around `liga`, however, this kind of code is *extremely* vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Whatever you're doing, I recommend looking for another solution.

Comment: p.s.w.g. is correct. It would really help if you explain what you are trying to accomplish, and why you think “use variable in Sql Command query” will help.

Comment: OK :). My intention is to call this code in 6 different web forms. On main administrator (only few persons will have access to this page) page will be 6 buttons: if someone will press "Spain League", the value "spain" will be passed in to web form, and using query string i want put this variable into sql command query string.

Comment: Anyway, thank You  p.s.w.g for answer, because it's working.

Comment: It may be working but it is not a good solution.  You really need to listen to p.s.w.g's comment.  Look for another solution.  Including the table name as a parameter to a sql statement is fragile at best and very open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Ok, i think i know how to change that. Thank You for advise !